# C# Windows Service that connects to network through VPN

Tags: c#, windows-services, vpn

I have a Windows Service that must connect, via VPN, to the network in order to send emails. What I need to do (when I start the service) is check whether the VPN connection exists, if not create it, and then connect to the network.

I was looking at [DotRAS](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) which looks ideal for doing all the work, however, it doesn't seem to provide a method for creating a new VPN connection.

So my question is, is there a way in which I can programmatically create a VPN connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, turns out [DotRAS](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120040549/http://dotras.codeplex.com:80/) *does* have a method for creating new VPN connections :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a scriptable VPN client, and run it using `Process.Start("path-to-your-script")`.

Depending on which client you use, you have different possibilities regarding monitoring the status of the VPN connection.

[Here is an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808073116/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/thibbard/articles/CSharpCodeToMaintainVPNConnectionProgramatically.aspx) where the Windows rasphone client is used in such a way.

Comment: Yeah I read that article, which led me to the DotRas component (see the comments on the article). I never actually thought of using a good old fashioned script! Thanks I will give it a go.